The equivalent (or near alternative) of com.ibm.websphere.tivoli.* for openliberty with java 17
As the title says, do you have:

Suggestions
Alternatives
An or have encountered this case that you have migrated to openliberty from websphere server?
Thank you!


What functionality are you trying to migrate that requires tivoli? Typically it is related to authentication/authorization, there are other ways to implement that in Liberty. You can also use WebSphere migration toolkit for binaries to scan the application and see suggested workarounds.

I have resorted to ldap of openliberty.
UPDATE
Thank you for bringing this up @Doug Breaux, as I was into updating my code, I forgot to update this post.
Moving on, what I did is a of combination of unboundid and vanilla Java LDAP to succeed in converting my methods. But, I plan to migrate it all in unboundid as I see it, it is being supported fairly good continuously.
Porting my code.
Here is the list of PDUser https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sva/10.0.7?topic=groups-administering-user-information methods that I have primarily used.
But since I will no longer use Websphere, I am now using Java LDAP Vanilla code like:
    String ldapUrl = "";
    String searchBase = "";
    String searchFilter = "cn="+userName;
    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

        if (results.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult result = results.next();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ctx.close();
    }

For unboundid java code, I have read through this https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/controls.html

You might give more detail on what you were trying to do and how this approach worked
